# In a triangulated category with coproducts any idempotent splits

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, triangulated-categories

> In a triangulated category with coproducts any idempotent splits.

Is there a proof of this fact different from that in [Neeman](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Neeman/triangulatedcats.pdf), Prop. 1.6.8? In particular I'm looking for one which doesn't use the notion of homotopy colimit.

Thanks.

Comment: All proofs of this I know of rely on the same variant of the Eilenberg swindle. The triangulation is irrelevant, it's a fact about (pre-)additive categories with countable (co)products (or (co)powers). The argument is due to Freyd and can be found in his *Splitting homotopy idempotents,* in: Proceedings of the Conference on Categorical Algebra, La Jolla, CA, 1965, Springer, New York, 1966, pp. 173–176. However, the proof is not really different from that given in Neeman.

Comment: Here's an [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53006/how-do-i-split-a-homotopy-idempotent) on that argument.